# Why the downloaded image from localhost using HttpWebRequest corrupted?

Tags: c#, io, system.net

The original image(.jpg) file size is 49kb but when after I downloaded it the file size is 87kb and is corrupted. But for text files, it works. What do I need to do for downloading images using HttpWebRequest or other System.Net class?
I'm using XAMPP for localhost.

```
//Usage: HttpDownload("http://www.localhost/files/imagine.jpg", "seo.jpg");

    static async void HttpDownload(string remoteFileOrUri, string localFileName)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(remoteFileOrUri));
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(localFileName));

        sw.Write(rdr.ReadToEnd());
        sw.Flush();

        rdr.Close();
        sw.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("fin!");
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` for things that are not text. When you use them, encoding is applied. [Read this to find out more](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use StreamReader and StreamWriter for things that are not text. When you use them, encoding is applied. Encoding doesn't mix well with arbitrary binary data, as [this blog](https://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx/) will attest to.

Instead you should use a simple `FileStream`:

```
using (var output = File.OpenWrite(localFileName))
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(output);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this may not be your only issue as GZip compression (if the server is using it) may also be presenting problems. You can account for this with a simple setting change:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(remoteFileOrUri));

request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();

using (var output = File.OpenWrite(localFileName))
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        await responseStream.CopyToAsync(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well but why was the downloaded file was different from the remoteFile size?

Comment: How are you measuring the size of the remote file?

Comment: right-click the file, select properties then see Size:

Comment: I have no idea why the size would be different. They should be byte-for-byte identical.